# How to stub exported function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have file foo.js:

```
export function bar (m) {
  console.log(m);
}
```

And another file that uses foo.js, cap.js:

```
import { bar } from 'foo';

export default m => {
  // Some logic that I need to test
  bar(m);
}
```

I have test.js:

```
import cap from 'cap'

describe('cap', () => {
  it('should bar', () => {
      cap('some');
  });
});
```

Somehow I need override implementation of `bar(m)` in test. Is there any way to do this?

P.S. I use babel, webpack and mocha.

Comment: where do you need to override in cap or test?

Comment: In test, actually I need this to isolate cap functionality from bar for testing purposes.

Comment: What version of babel are you using?

Comment: @DavinTryon 6.3.15, I can actually use any if that matters.

Comment: If you use babel 5, you can use this plugin: https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire.  But it doesn't support babel 6 yet.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Ouch.. I found solution, so I use `sinon` to stub and `import * as foo from 'foo'` to get object with all exported functions so I can stub them.

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import cap from 'cap';
import * as foo from 'foo';

sinon.stub(foo, 'bar', m => {
    console.log('confirm', m);
});

describe('cap', () => {
  it('should bar', () => {
    cap('some');
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in an actual (non-babel-transpiled) ES6 environment

Comment: @Bergi yep, per my current understanding export actually exports immutable object, and because right now this implemented using regular objects it might fail later on.

Comment: This doesn't work like @MikeChaliy mentioned. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is working for me in a Node typescript (non-Babel) project

Comment: Sonar flags this and recommends that only the method needed be imported

Comment: This feature has been removed since `sinon 3.0.0`- see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138038/7962589

Answer (score 10):

You can replace/rewrite/stub exports only from within the module itself. (Here's an [explanation](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values))

If you rewrite 'foo.js' like this:

```
var bar = function bar (m) {
  console.log(m);
};

export {bar}

export function stub($stub) {
  bar = $stub;
}
```

You can then override it in your test like this:

```
import cap from 'cap'
import {stub} from 'foo'

describe('cap', () => {
  it('should bar', () => {
      stub(() => console.log('stubbed'));
      cap('some'); // will output 'stubbed' in the console instead of 'some'
  });
});
```

I've created a Babel plugin that transforms all the exports automatically so that they can be stubbed: https://github.com/asapach/babel-plugin-rewire-exports

Answer (score 4):

While @Mike solution would work in old versions of sinon, it has been removed since sinon 3.0.0.

Now instead of:

```
sinon.stub(obj, "meth", fn);
```

you should do:

```
stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)
```

Example of mocking google oauth api:

```
import google from 'googleapis';

const oauth2Stub = sinon.stub(); 

sinon.stub(google, 'oauth2').callsFake(oauth2Stub);

oauth2Stub.withArgs('v2').returns({
    tokeninfo: (accessToken, params, callback) => {
        callback(null, { email: 'poo@bar.com' }); // callback with expected result
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the original question about faking exported function in sinon 3.x. Can you extend your answer to address the original question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) (`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-rewire`)

And then in `test.js` use the `__Rewire__` function on the imported module to replace the function in that module:

```
// test.js
import sinon from 'sinon'

import cap from 'cap'

describe('cap', () => {
  it('should bar', () => {
    const barStub = sinon.stub().returns(42);
    cap.__Rewire__('bar', barStub); // <-- Magic happens here
    cap('some');
    expect(barStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Be sure to add `rewire` to your babel plugins in `.babelrc`:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "rewire"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, as you can see the `babel-plugin-rewire` plugin is only enabled in the test environment, so you should call you test runner with the `BABEL_ENV` environment variable set to `test` (which you're probably doing already):

```
env BABEL_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test-example.js
```

Note: I couldn't get `babel-plugin-rewire-exports` to work.

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely a gotcha for me too...

I created a little util to workaround this limitation of sinon. (Available in [js too](https://gist.github.com/mfbx9da4/84834b7e0696c3e70553edb53d7609e0)).

```
// mockable.ts
```

```js
import sinon from 'sinon'

export function mockable<T extends unknown[], Ret>(fn: (...fnArgs: T) => Ret) {
  let mock: sinon.SinonStub<T, Ret> | undefined
  const wrapper = (...args: T) => {
    if (mock) return mock(...args)
    return fn(...args)
  }
  const restore = () => {
    mock = undefined
  }
  wrapper.mock = (customMock?: sinon.SinonStub<T, Ret>) => {
    mock = customMock || sinon.stub()
    return Object.assign(mock, { restore })
  }
  wrapper.restore = restore
  return wrapper
}
```

If you paste the above snippet into your project you can use it like so

### foo.js

```js
import { mockable } from './mockable'

// we now need to wrap the function we wish to mock
export const foo = mockable((x) => {
   console.log(x)
})
```

### main.js

```js
import { foo } from './foo'

export const main = () => {
  foo('asdf') // use as normal
}
```

### test.js

```js
import { foo } from './foo'
import { main } from './main'

// mock the function - optionally pass in your own mock
const mock = foo.mock()

// test the function
main()
console.assert(mock.calledOnceWith('asdf'), 'not called')

// restore the function
stub.restore()
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to remember to always import the function in a certain way. `import { foo } from './foo'` works just as well as `import * as foo from './foo'`. Automatic imports will likely just work in your IDE.