# Sinon not working for exported function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I have a really simple JS lib (called trysinon.js) that looks like this:

```
export function foo() {
  bar();
}

export function bar() {
 return 2;
}
```

And I have the following test

```
import expect from 'expect';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as trysinon from 'trysinon';

describe('trying sinon', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(trysinon, 'bar');
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    trysinon.bar.restore();
  });

  it('calls bar', function() {
    trysinon.foo();
    expect(trysinon.bar.called).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And the test is failing. How can I ensure the test passes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stub exported function in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40267448/8035178)

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: see the linked answer from DreamSonic (not the accepted one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `foo()`, you called `bar()` which is inner function of trysinon.js. This `bar()` is different with the `bar()` you stubbed which is exported. The best way is to change `trysinon` to class, or called exported `bar()` in `foo()` as following.

```
function bar() { return 2; }
module.exports.bar = bar;

function foo() {
  module.exports.bar();
}
module.exports.foo = foo;
```

then you can stub `bar()` with `sinon.stub(trysinon, 'bar').returns(2)`

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I use arrow function instead, and it works.

```js
export const foo = () => {
  bar();
}

export const bar = () => {
 return 2;
}
```