# stub an object without requiring a method

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon, stub, request-promise

I have something like:

```
sandbox.stub(rp, 'get').resolves(successResponse)
```

which returns my custom response when it hits this code:

```
return await rp.get(url, options)
```

But how can I do something like this:

```
    sandbox.stub(rp).resolves(successResponse)
```

Which can return a custom response when it hits this code?

```
    return await rp(url, options)
```

When I attempt "stubbing" the entire object, I get this error when I run the test:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
      at wrapMethod (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\util\core\wrap-method.js:70:21)
      at stub (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\stub.js:58:44)
      at Object.stub (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\collection.js:93:33)
```

`rp` is [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native), which wraps [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: Not an answer, but why not just make your own stub. The code will be simpler: `rp.get = () => Promise.resolve(stubresponse)`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072016/stubbing-a-class-method-with-sinon-js)

Comment: @Troopers sorry, that issue is different than my case. That problem follows the `(class, method)` pattern, but my call to `rp` doesn't fit that.

Comment: @Houseman : Show us how you define `rp` in the second case.

Comment: [Similar question with es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575750/how-to-stub-exported-function-in-es6)

Comment: @Troopers I've edited the question to show how I define `rp`. The similar es6 question doesn't quite fit, because that's still `foo.bar()`. For it to be equivalent, it would have to be just `foo()`.

Comment: [Third try](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/664)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Troopers' link in the comments above, it seems like this isn't possible: [Doing this is not technically possible without faking the entire module loading system.](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/664#issuecomment-71980876)

So I followed the suggestion here: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2181 and used mock-require to stub `rp`. I also changed up my code that used to call `rp.get()`, so that it just calls `rp()`, since I couldn't also figure out how to stub both `rp()` and `rp.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Sinon HowTo about Link Seams helpful: http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/