# Stubbing single exported function with Sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

I have just changed my lodash import from `import _ from 'lodash';` to `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';`
In my test I used to have `sandbox.stub(_, 'debounce').returnsArg(0);`, but now I'm stuck as to what to change it to. Obviously `sandbox.stub(debounce).returnsArg(0);` won't work. Not sure what to do when only a single function is exported from a module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stub exported function in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575750/how-to-stub-exported-function-in-es6)

Answer (score 11):

This syntax:

```
import something from 'myModule';
```

...is ES6 syntax which binds `something` to the `default` export of `'myModule`'.

If the module is an ES6 module then you can stub the `default` export of the module like this:

```
import * as myModule from 'myModule';
const sinon = require('sinon');

// ...

const stub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'default');
```

...but this only works if `'myModule'` is an ES6 module.

In this case `'lodash/debounce'` is not an ES6 module, it is shipped pre-compiled.  The last line is this:

```
module.exports = debounce;
```

...which means the module export *is* the debounce function.

This means that in order to stub `'lodash/debounce'` you have to mock the entire module.

Sinon doesn't provide module-level mocking so you will need to use something like [`proxyquire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire):

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const debounceStub = sinon.stub().returnsArg(0);
const code = proxyquire('[path to your code]', { 'lodash/debounce': debounceStub })
```

...or if you are using [`Jest`](https://jestjs.io/) you can use something like `jest.mock`:

```
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () =>
  jest.fn((func, ms) => func)  // <= mock debounce to simply return the function
);
```

---

**Details**

The reason that stubbing the `default` export of a module only works if it is an ES6 module is because of what happens during compilation.

ES6 syntax gets compiled into pre-ES6 JavaScript.  For example, Babel turns this:

```
import something from 'myModule';
```

...into this:

```
var _myModule = _interopRequireDefault(require("myModule"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
  return obj && obj.__esModule ?
    obj :  // <= return the result of require("myModule") if it is an ES6 module...
    { default: obj };  // <= otherwise set it to the default property of a wrapper object
}
```

...so if `'myModule'` is an ES6 module it gets returned directly...but if it is not then the interop returns a wrapping object.

Since each `import` gets a different wrapping object, changing the `default` property on one doesn't affect the `default` property of any others.

Comment: Fantastic. I thought it would require a new library or something.

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed` error, any clue?

Comment: This is actually not accurate.
ES modules cannot be altered at run time, unlike CJS modules.
This is because of the immutability of the ES module cache.
You cannot stub an ES module using Sinon. You need a specific mocking solution such as esmock or mockingbird for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can make yourself a wrapping file, which will eventually export the same `lodash/debounce` instance for you, but this time you could stub that, e.g.:

**myutils/lodash/debounce.js**

```
import lodashDebounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const exports = {
    debounce: lodashDebounce,
};

export const debounce = () => exports.debounce();

export default exports;
```

now, in your actual code import the `debounce` not from the original location, but from this wrapping file instead:

**BEFORE:**

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce' // this is how we usually do
```

**AFTER:**

```
import { debounce } from 'myutils/lodash/debounce' // if we want to stub it


// all other code-lines remain the same
const method = () => {
    debounce(callback, 150));
    ...
}
```

now when doing a **test.js**:

```
import lodashWrapped from 'myutils/lodash/debounce';

sinon.stub(lodashWrapped , 'debounce').callsFake((callbackFn) => {
  // this is stubbed now
});

// go on, make your tests now
```