# Cypress , test-vue-utils : how to use mock an api call with an action in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, cypress, stub, web-api-testing

I would like to test an action , my action contains an api call

my action in vuex

File containts actions in my store ( store 'ex.js' )
**exActions.js**

```js
export const exActions = {
    getExFromApi({ commit, rootGetters }, { id }) {
        getApiExById({ access_token: rootGetters.auth.token, id }).then(res => {
            commit('SET_INIT_EX', res)
            commit('SET_CURRENT_EX', res)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.warn(error)
        })
    },
```

File containt call api
**exAPi.js**

```js
export const getApiExById= (params, group) => {
    // call return promise
}
```

My File test

```js
// import api
const api = require('../../../src/api/exAPi')
let store = null

describe('Unit Test', function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const localVue = createLocalVue()
        localVue.use(Vuex)
        store = new Vuex.Store({
            modules: {
                exStore
            }
        })
    })
    context('test : action -> getExFromApi', function() {
        it('1',  async function() {
          let rootGetters = {
                auth: {
                    token: 'aaa'
                }
            }
            let commit = cy.spy()
            // mock call api , return a promise defined
            cy.stub(api, 'getApiExById').resolved('foo')
            
            // start the method 
            await store.dispatch('getExFromApi', ({commit, rootGetters}, {id: '1'}))

            // expect 'foo' value because cy.stub api return 'foo'
            expect(commit.args).to.deep.equal([
              ['SET_INIT_EX', 'foo'],
              ['SET_CURRENT_EX', 'foo']
            ])

           cy.stub.restore()
```

start file with node -> ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open-ct
The problem, the 'getExFromApi' start but launch the real call api and not the mock.

I do anything wrong ?  thanks you for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you import api into the test, it's not the same instance as the app is using.

```js
const api = require('../../../src/api/exAPi')   // creates a new instance
```

To get the same instance, in store **ex.js**

```js
import * as api from '../api/exAPi'   // import module
const {getApiExById} = api       // method for use in exActions 

if (window.Cypress) {            // are we testing?
  window.api = api               // allow test to see module instance
}
```

In test

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  // mock call api , return a promise defined
  cy.stub(win.api, 'getApiExById').resolved('foo')   // mocking the same instance
}
```

I'm a bit wary of the `cy.window().then(`, maybe this is better

```js
// mock call api , return a promise defined
const win = cy.state('window');
cy.stub(win.api, 'getApiExById').resolved('foo')   // mocking the same instance
```

**Importing the module in ex.js**

Because you're using a named export in `exApi.js` but the stub is failing, I presume there's no default export, i.e the module is **not** exported like this

```js
...
export default {
  getApiExById
}
```

If so, change the default import in `ex.js` to

```js
import * as api from '../api/exAPi'   // import module
...
```

Ref [How to stub exported function in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575750/how-to-stub-exported-function-in-es6)

Comment: ok win.api has my api function .    but if i run my dispatch(             await store.dispatch('getExFromApi') )  I start the real api call , not the api mock.

I need to modify my action ? hum

Comment: I see the problem - `exApi.js` needs a default export. Will add it above.